# Here API: Geocoding Free-Text Query Returns Correct Result But Qualified Query Doesn't

Tags: here-api

I'm experiencing this weird response from the Geocoding API where, in searching for a known address, it would return the correct geocoding result for a free-text query ("q") but return an empty result for the qualified query ("qq") even though the address details are correctly compartmentalized to each field as returned by the free-text query

https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=REMOVED&in=countryCode:AUS&q=Unit+10%2F232A+MAIN+RD++MAROOCHYDORE+4558+QLD+Australia

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Main Rd, Maroochydore QLD 4558, Australia",
            "id": "here:af:street:c3mXot9HjZRObEAATNdRhC",
            "resultType": "street",
            "address": {
                "label": "Main Rd, Maroochydore QLD 4558, Australia",
                "countryCode": "AUS",
                "countryName": "Australia",
                "state": "Queensland",
                "city": "Sunshine Coast",
                "district": "Maroochydore",
                "street": "Main Rd",
                "postalCode": "4558"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": -26.65569,
                "lng": 153.06295
            },
            "mapView": {
                "west": 153.05138,
                "south": -26.66196,
                "east": 153.07228,
                "north": -26.65418
            },
            "scoring": {
                "queryScore": 0.77,
                "fieldScore": {
                    "country": 1.0,
                    "state": 1.0,
                    "district": 1.0,
                    "streets": [
                        1.0
                    ],
                    "postalCode": 1.0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=REMOVED&in=countryCode:AUS&qq=street=MAIN+RD;district=MAROOCHYDORE;postalCode=4558;state=QLD

```
{
    "items": []
}
```

How often does this inconsistent behaviour occur and what could I implement to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try using below request call to check whether it is returning the correct data as you expected it to be. Below works for us.

https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=xxxxx&in=countryCode:AUS&qq=country=Australia;state=Queensland;district=MAROOCHYDORE;street=MAIN RD;postalCode=4558;

There won't be inconsistency if the query would be structured. please report if you encounter such more issues. It is advisable to go from more generic to more specifc while specify the structure in the query